# Open/Close multiple div with external content loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

I'm trying to create a portfolio that loads external content when clicking on "read more".
Loading external content works fine and the div animates as it should. I even got the same div to close and open when I click on another "read more" link.

My problem is that when I click on the same "read more" link the div don't close, it just animates and load the external content again.

I hope this makes sense...

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="portfolio-content"></div>
            <div id="isotope-container">
                <div class="element webdesign">
                    <header>
                        <h3>Test title: Webdesign</h3>
                    </header>
                    <img src="images/test_img_01.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
                    <ul class="meta clearfix">
                        <li>Filter:</li>
                        <li><a href="" title="Webdesign">Webdesign</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="read-more">
                        <a href="portfolio-pages/page_1.html" title="Read more &rarr;" class="more">Read more &rarr;</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="element advertisement">
                    <header>
                        <h3>Test title: Advertisement</h3>
                    </header>
                    <img src="images/test_img_02.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
                    <ul class="meta clearfix">
                        <li>Filter:</li>
                        <li><a href="" title="Advertisement">Advertisement</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="read-more">
                        <a href="portfolio-pages/page_2.html" title="Read more &rarr;" class="more">Read more &rarr;</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".more").click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if ($('#portfolio-content').is(':visible')) {
        $('#portfolio-content').css({display:'block'}).animate({height:'1px'}).empty();
    }

    $('#portfolio-content').css({display:'block'}).animate({height:'200px'},function(){
        $('#portfolio-content').html('<img class="loader" src="http://dev.push-media.no/final_site/images/loader.gif" alt="">');
        $("#portfolio-content").load(href);
    });

    return false;
});

$(".more").next().click(function(){
    $("#portfolio-content").fadeOut('normal');
});
});
```

Comment: share your code here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sorknes/f8Dfb/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're doing more than you need to when #portfolio-content is visible. Maybe try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/f8Dfb/3

```
#portfolio-content {
    display: none;
}

if ($('#portfolio-content').is(':visible')) {
    $('#portfolio-content').slideUp();
}

$('#portfolio-content').css({
    display: 'block', height: '0'
}).animate({
    height: '200px'
}, function () {
...
```

Comment: Updated again to fix height animation.

Comment: I only see a + button in the third item, and the layout seems broken. Firefox/Win7.

Comment: Please try again now? I added some CSS to temporarily fix the problem.